# Netlify CMS offline local host

Tags: netlify-cms

I would like to run the NetlifyCMS locally but in an offline environment.

I was looking here: https://www.netlifycms.org/docs/authentication-backends/ and am wondering about attributes such as "auth_type". My two main questions are:

1) I have a legitimate application_id, etc. If I enter those, but run it offline, will it work? 
2) Is there an "auth_type" value that I can use to disable authentication all together.

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: There is not really a way to disable auth without using `test-repo` as a backend. NetlifyCMS uses git for backends (GitHub, GitLab, Bitbucket supported). Not sure what you are defining as `offline`? What is the expectation for an update into the CMS?

Comment: by offline I mean without access to the internet. I think I fixed the issue though, thank you!

Comment: @blubberbo So how'd you fix it?

Comment: I solved it in an unrelated way unfortunately. I couldn't find a way to run it offline - you need connectivity to a Git instance. There is no way to disable auth all together as far as I have found.

Answer (score 4):

Netlify has launched a beta feature which allows working with local repo.

1. Navigate to a local Git repository configured with the CMS.
2. Run npx netlify-cms-proxy-server from the root directory of the above repository.
3. Update your config.yml to connect to the server:

```
backend:
  name: proxy
  proxy_url: http://localhost:8081/api/v1
  branch: master # optional, defaults to master
```

You can check more details [here](https://www.netlifycms.org/docs/beta-features/#working-with-a-local-git-repository)